# My new Github page isn't showing up

Tags: git, github, github-pages

So I'm following [this guide here to create a Github page](http://pages.github.com/)

I created a repository, cloned it to my project directory and pushed, finally got to this last step:

```
Fire up a browser and go to http://username.github.io. Give it a couple of minutes for your page to show up—there will be a delay this very first time. In the future, changes will show up pretty much instantly.
```

My Github repo link is this:
https://github.com/leongaban/gabanco

So I assumed my Github page link would be either:
http://leongaban.gabanco.github.io/

or

http://leongaban.github.io/

However neither link is working at the moment :(

Anyone create a Github page before? Eventually I want to try out Jekyll on it.

Comment: check offical docs [here](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rename your repository to `<yourusername>.github.io` as explained [in the documentation](https://docs.github.com/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites).

> To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `<user>.github.io`.

**Edit:**
You can only use your own account name for a User or Org Pages repository. A repository like joe/bob.github.io will not build Pages.

Comment: OH! Thanks! http://leongaban.studiogaban.github.io/ going to see if it will be there in 10 mins now :)

Comment: `leongaban.studiogaban.github.io` is not correct ,you should use your own gitHub user name . try `leongaban.github.io`

Comment: ugh I don't understand. leongaban is my username, my project name is studiogaban?

Comment: yes,if your user name is leongaban, your project name should also be `leongaban.github.io`.now your project name is `gabanco`, so this cause the mistake i edited in the answer above. so just try rename your project->`gabanco` to `leongaban.github.io`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44370/discussion-between-leon-gaban-and-johnma)

Comment: why doesnt it work with www.username.github.io? only https://username.github.io works

Comment: Should that "@" sign be in the answer?

Answer (score 64):

Try to push an empty commit and refresh the page. It should work.

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger rebuild"
git push
```

Comment: I want to give this more upvotes: it worked for me and it may be a necessary step.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I thought it might be the issue with the old cache being served. But this command does the work for sure. Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works for me! Could you explain more?

Comment: The only method to start the build is to use Git. Sometimes you may not be able to manually initiate the build or you'll need to start a build without making any changes to project

Answer (score 59):

I'm not sure if the site just needed some time to show up, but I was getting a 404 error after pushing my master branch... Then I changed my 'theme' in the repo's settings. All of a sudden it started working! A file called `config.yml` appeared with the theme metadata.

Comment: same for me, not sure why theme is now required!

Comment: Wow, this works. Is it a bug on Github Pages? Or is this intended functionality?

Comment: I encoutered the same as well. Although this is never mentioned in the [guide](https://pages.github.com/) . I wonder if this is mandatory.

Comment: 2020 and same here. Just set the theme and made the name the name of the org in lowercase and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

If you have the correct repository name and you still get a 404 error a solution might be to push to the repository.

This is what worked for me. After the push it showed up instantly.

Comment: This is also something which worked for me. I just pushed a README file and site showed up after some minutes.

Comment: yes, it also works smoothly for me. Just curious why them did't include it in tutorial.

Answer (score 10):

Name your repository correctly, as stated in the first step:

> Head over to GitHub and create a new repository named
>   **username.github.io**, where username is your username (or organization
>   name) on GitHub.

Comment: Is username case-sensitive?

Comment: no, if you set the username like AbCd.github.io   ,   the final link to your page will be abcd.github.io

Answer (score 10):

As of 2022, having created a repository,

1. I had to navigate to project settings,
2. then *Pages*,
3. then click *Enable* (or similar), choose the branch I'd like to use (`master` in my case), save,
4. then push a single commit to refresh GitHub Pages.

Project was hosted instantly under `https://USERNAME.github.io/PROJECTNAME/`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by going to the `Settings` for the repository and changing the name of the Repository to `username.github.io`

Comment: Even though the tutorial clearly states what the correct name of the repo should be, I somehow still managed to not read carefully and ended up with an ubiquitous 404 because I missed the ".github.io" as part of the name. Talk about not following a basic guide properly! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What I did was to add a README.md file. I typed something in the README.md and committed the change to the `main` branch and immediately, the page started showing. Here it is: https://akcumeh.github.io/03-sunnyside

Interestingly, I've never had to do that before to be able to view my site, but I had to do that today. I think someone mentioned this in a previous answer on this same thread...

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the correct repository name and still got a 404 error. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36482193/2611620) answer, so I made a change and pushed again. This time the changes from my first push showed up. So I waited for a while and then few minutes later, the changes from my second pushed showed up. It might just be the case that changes are not visible instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

For me the second commit directly shown my Github page.
[This](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/) is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you have named your repository correctly like `<username>.github.io`, and it is showing Github pages is under maintenance, then wait for a few minutes and then refresh. Your site will show up.

But, if it is showing 404 error, then check if you have index.html in your root folder and your Github pages setting is enabled from the settings tab.

Go to this link - `https://github.com/<username>/<username>.github.io/settings`
And check Github Pages section in which you have to configure the Source.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply change the folder from **root** to **docs** or **vice versa**.

*It worked for me.*

Answer (score 2):

Usually we can see the build pipeline and find out what the issue is.
For example, In my case I am able to see files in commit and also generated html file. But unfortunately, I am not able to see and browse to that page.

[image]

We can navigate to last commit and next to our commit id, we can see a green tick mark. When we click on that tick mark, we can see build and deployment info something like this.

[image]

We can expand each step and see where exactly the issue is. In my case, after expanding build, I saw that my page is skipped

[image]

Problem here is, I gave date in my Jekyll admin and posted it. But GitHub is taking UTC date and I am from IST. So my time is still future time for GitHub.
So I made sure that I gave delayed time and it worked.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that I can debug gihub! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think first you need to check out if YOUR Github Pages have been enabled. This you can check out from "setting". Then change whatever html web site 
from"github.com/username/repo1/repo2/repo3.../blob/master/file.html"

to "username.github.io/repo1/repo2/repo3.../file.html" .

Then have a try.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my page repository uses the username/username.github.io naming scheme, but still cannot work.

I just clone the repository to local, and new a push_test.txt file and push it to the repository, and then https://username.github.io works.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had an error in my html file "No newline at end of file".  Once I fixed this problem and did another Commit and Push, it worked.

Comment: How did you debug this?

Comment: Turns out you can view build errors under repository settings in GitHub. Neat!

Comment: No. this can not be a reason. A newline on html page does not cause errors. I checked it!!

Answer (score 1):

go to project settings, and scroll down, find the github pages section. it might say you haven't choose a source. i chose one, and wait for 2 minutes, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GitHub user name in the repository name first part. Wait 2 minutes after adding your age. Use google webmaster search console to verify the page you created in GitHub pages[image].

```
rahul-inspired-iosdeveloper.github.io
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that solved the 404 error page was to change the Branch from Master to gt-pages

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have followed everything told in the steps such as :
Repository name should be username.github.io

The main thing is you must add **READ.md file** to your repository. For sure your website will show up.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Angular app. I forgot to make repo public :) Even tho i didn't use the username/username.github.io repo naming scheme it worked at `<username>.github.io/<repo-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

My page was working, but then I tried to connect it to Heroku which led to a 404 error.  After switching back to the original, I still got the error.  I got around this by going in the settings of the repo and actually changing the name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that index.html file is present in your code otherwise it will give 400 error

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable Git Pages
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

One other datapoint: check your branch.

When you create a new repo, the default branch is "main". The branch required for the GitHub page is "master".

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is using the gh-pages NPM library to deploy (i.e. for a React app), you need to do one more step after deploying.

From your GitHub settings page, scroll down to "GitHub Pages" and change the source branch to "gh-pages". This branch should created automatically for you once you deploy your app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened because i had my index.html file inside a folder from a main branch. For it to work you must have a file ***index.html*** directly just inside your first repositories not in any folders or sub-folders inside it. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not panic and rename your GitHub Repository and view your page it gets uploaded and you can rename it to original name then after.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the theme worked for me as well. Initially I thought I might have to wait longer for the index file to load, but it hasn't taken that long on prior repo's I have done.

Steps:

1. Click on Settings in the Repo
2. Click on Pages
3. Click Change Theme

Simply add a theme and it should load the published page url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add readme file, because after I waited 15 minutes I added it, after that it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the settings of your project to enable it:

```
Setting > GitHub Pages >Build and deployment > Branches
```

(the main branch must be selected)

Answer (score 0):

The index page as in whatever.html has to say index.html; I've tried to publish a site and forgot all about that wow three times and finally published