# Github page: why does it now show my page?

Tags: github, jekyll

I followed really really simple tutorial to make my own `github` blog using `jekyll`.

Here is what I simlely do:

1. In my local computer directory,
2. `jekyll new my-awesome-site`
3. Test in local by `bundle exec jekyll serve`

   - It works quite well and shows sample jekyll page!
4. Create the repository for the blog in github, named [abc.github.io](https://github.com/abc/abc.github.io), which is `https://github.com/abc/abc.github.io` as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895602/3595632) indicates
5. Push my blog dir to the github remote repository.
6. Go to `Settings` and change the name of repo to `abc.github.io`

This is my settings and it shows that my site is published!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It's been 24hours after I've seen this msg and browser still doesn't shows even sample page!

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What's wrong with it?

Need your helps and advices Thanks!

Comment: What theme are you using? I see 'architect' in the _config...

Comment: Yes, I chose `architect`. Is that a problem?

Comment: Does the site render properly on GitHub Pages if you choose `minima` instead of `architect` or `cayman` theme?

Comment: @ashmaroli, Jesus! it works after changing to default theme! Why can't I change the theme?

Comment: delete `_site` and `Gemfile.lock` from your repository.. To ensure `_site` doesn't get added again in the future, add it to a `.gitignore` file and commit the `.gitignore` file to your repo..

Comment: Actually, those were added in `.gitignore` before, but after site failed to show, I tried to add them.... even though this doesn't change anything(site doesn't work in both cases). But this one is not related with site working, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this issue because the [Architect theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/architect) has a different structure than the default theme, and Jekyll is not able to build the website after you push because of a missing layout.

[image]

For instance, in your [index.md](https://github.com/rightx2/rightx2.github.io/blob/master/index.md) file you are referencing a layout called `home`, but as [you can see in the Architect's theme source code](https://github.com/pages-themes/architect/tree/master/_layouts), it only has one layout, called `default`.

If you change your `index.md` to point to the `default` layout, it will render correctly the structure of the main page.

You'll have to check other layouts as well, in posts, etc. The best is to follow the instructions described in the theme you want to implement, in this case the Architect: https://github.com/pages-themes/architect

---

ps: You also need to delete the folder `_site` (and commit it) and make sure you have it in the `.gitignore` so it doesn't get committed again in the future.

Comment: Great answer. However, this is another great example why the (current) implementation of themes in Jekyll is wrong/too difficult for beginners.

Comment: @JoostS I agree. It easier when themes were together with the site and less “magic” was going on. But really GitHub pages needs to improve on displaying build error messages.

Comment: That is also true.

Comment: @CaioProiete While your logic is correct, this is not the reason why the user is seeing a non-rendered page.. GitHub Pages will automatically use the `default` layout if the currently requested layout (`home` in this case) cannot be found.. It does this via the `jekyll-default-layout` plugin